# Let me rearrange icons on my KDE desktop (like Windows)

Tags: kde, desktop, icons

I was a Windows user for the past few years. I moved to Linux due to bad system stability and frequent blue screens. I tested few of the desktop environments. I like KDE but I don't like its "static" desktop feeling, I mean I can't move icons wherever I want and I can't create documents on my desktop from context menu. There is also no selection box like Windows and desktop environments like Cinnamon, mate and xfce have. Is this possible to change KDE desktop to act similar to Windows? I really can't get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found solution myself so I post it here:
Right click on desktop -> Desktop Settings -> Layout and I changed layout from there and it works ;)